# Поиск постов по городу: наиболее оптимальный вариант?

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте, в общем есть много-много постов, у каждого поста есть `t.location` и `t.id_city`, в `location` написан полный адрес например: "Россия, г. Екатеринбург, ул. Пушкина дом 7", Так вот, нужно вырвать из базы данных по городу, как лучше это сделать:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  post t
WHERE
  t.id_city = :id_city
```

или

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  post t
WHERE
  t.location LIKE %:location% //:location => 'Екатеринбург'
```

буду очень рад если дадите более оптимальный вариант

Comment: Конечно лучше искать по id_city.

Comment: o'k, спасибо.

Comment: Искать по location лучше только в том случае, если по каким-то причинам индекс стоит только на location

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев*

Конечно поиск будет гораздо быстрее числовому полю `id_city`. Искать по второму варианту возможно лучше только в том случае, если по каким-то причинам индекс стоит только на поле `location`.